# How do I navigate to a parent StackNavigator from a nested toptabnavigator?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to use this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailScreen") in my createMaterialTopTabNavigator screens to redirect to the DetailScreen in the StackNavigator but I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined', how can I structure my code to prevent it? Navigating from DetailScreen to Leaderboard works, but not the other way.

```
const LeaderBoardWrapperView = createStackNavigator({
Leaderboard: {
screen: Leaderboard = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({
  Alltime: () =>
    <AllTimeLeaderBoard path="allTime" />,
  Semester: () =>
    <AllTimeLeaderBoard path="semester" />,
  Weekly: () =>
    <AllTimeLeaderBoard path="weekly" />,
   })
  },
   DetailScreen: {
     screen: DetailScreen,
   }
})
```

[Picture of my code with better formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne9KY.png)

Answer (score 1):

navigation is not passed as a property to your top tab screen.
so you must pass this. for example:

```
Alltime: ({navigation}) =>
    <AllTimeLeaderBoard navigation={navigation} path="allTime" />
```

Comment: This time I get "refererence error navigation is not defined"